# ActiveRecord query based on status of associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having trouble to build this query in ActiveRecord:

Return a list of unique documents that have no completed or active print jobs.

So the query should include documents that have either no print jobs at all or only aborted print jobs.

Here are the models and relevant attributes:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :print_jobs
end

class PrintJob < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: { active: 0, completed: 1, aborted: 2 }

  belongs_to :document
end
```

My first attempt was to get a list of all completed or active print jobs, and find all documents that are not associated with these print jobs:

```
Document.where.not(id: PrintJob.active_or_completed.select(:document_id))
```

But I wonder if this is the right "SQL-ish" way of doing such queries.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What if you would try a `includes(:print_jobs)`? There is an example in answers. Does that run faster?

Comment: `includes(:print_jobs)` leaves out some of the wanted documents without print jobs (see comment on your answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you do it absolutely makes sense. Adding little optimization suggested by @Aleks:

```
Document.where.not(id: PrintJob.active_or_completed.document_ids)
```

EDIT: Updated to reflect latest status of discussion. Removed suggestion to use pluck. It's of no use here.

Comment: Why using `pluck` in this case? The `rails` way for this would be `PrintJob.active_or_completed.document_ids`, but this is still not perfect as if you would have too many `id's` it will result in veryy slow response

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried both versions. When I use `pluck` then a large array gets inserted into the SQL with currently 33443 entries and it takes longer to execute. The "select-version" also produces cleaner SQL: `SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents" WHERE ("documents"."id" NOT IN (SELECT "print_jobs"."document_id" FROM "print_jobs" WHERE "print_jobs"."status" IN (0, 1)))` Next time I will check the SQL first. Thanks again!

Comment: good to know, I wasn't even aware of @Aleks version. Has this been there in Rails 3?

Comment: heh, I don't remember if it was in Rails 3 :)  @BjörnAlbers yes, a bit cleaner, but what if you would need to change status you would need to know which status is what number. Better would be to use `('status = ?',[status[:active],status[:completed]])`, but ok, if you are only one working on it, then all is good, but if not, then the other programmer is in problem :)

Comment: I think @Aleks first answer here is the most elegant approach and as far as I understand meets all requirements. so it would be ultimately:
    `Document.where.not(id: PrintJob.active_or_completed.document_ids)`

Answer (score 0):

`Document.joins(:print_jobs).where.not(status: [0,1]).uniq` should do the job.

Comment: I would explicitly state that status is on the `print_jobs` table: `where.not('print_jobs.status = ?'....`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your query raises an  error: Document.joins(:print_jobs).where.not('print_jobs.status = ?', [0, 1]).uniq.count                                                                                               
   (25.2ms)  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "documents"."id") FROM "documents" INNER JOIN "print_jobs" ON "print_jobs"."document_id" = "documents"."id" WHERE (NOT (print_jobs.status = 0,1))
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of NOT must be type boolean, not type record

Answer (score 0):

This is all SQL way of doing this without selecting `id's` and running two separate queries:

```
Document.includes(:print_jobs).where.not( :print_jobs => { status: [statuses[:active], statuses[:completed]] } )
```

It will select all the documents which can join `PrintJobs` that are of status active or completed

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This raises "NameError: undefined local variable or method `status'". Also this does not include documents without print jobs.

Comment: Hm, yes, sorry it should have been `statuses` instead of `status`. I have updated it.

Comment: Hm, I didn't realize that there would be documents without print-jobs, I taught selecting only documents only without those print jobs. In that case you could merge those two queries, but hm, let me think.

Comment: Hey Aleks, no worries. I'm gonna stick with my first attempt which passes all specs. Your argument to not hard-code status codes into the query totally makes sense. Thats why I'm gonna keep it hidden in the scope `PrintJob.active_or_completed`. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: you should NEVER use a query part on a `includes` table without a `references`. This is asking for trouble...

Comment: That's wrong opinion. It is like I would say you should NEVER use a table name in SQL query without reverencing - which means you should never use `select * from table`, and I should always use`select * from table t`, which is a non-seance. It makes a difference when referencing multiple sub-queries in `includes`, but not in a simple query like this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a special scope inside your Document model which simply returns you the desired result. Because you shouldn't expose your query logic out of model.
Also, it's better to add corresponding scope into your PrintJob model so it will be possible to define additional has_many association at Document for scoped PrintJob.

As [Aleks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1612469/aleks) already mentioned it's better to do all work on the database layer and don't extract all ids of PrintJob and pass them into the query, because it might slow down the performance significantly. So it's better to do it with a single SQL query.

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :print_jobs

  # Here we can define association with scope which applies scope defined in PrintJob
  has_many :not_active_or_completed_print_jobs, -> { not_active_or_completed }, class_name: 'PrintJob'

  # I believe that there is a shorter name exists for such sort of documents
  def self.without_active_or_completed_jobs
    distinct.joins(:not_active_or_completed_print_jobs)
  end
end

class PrintJob < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: { active: 0, completed: 1, aborted: 2 }

  belongs_to :document

  def self.not_active_or_completed
    where.not(status: [statuses[:active], statuses[:completed]])
  end
end
```

After that you can call it like this:

```
Document.without_active_or_completed_jobs
```